# How can I make my logo look the way I want with CSS?

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

I have created a logo using HTML and CSS. My questions are:

- How do I center the text relative to the line (as opposed to the page)?
- How do I cause the text to be directly above and below the line?

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    .hr{
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      width: 35%;
    }
    .logo{
      top:0;
      left:0;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>GTD</h1>
      <hr>
      <h3>Web Design</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you have 2 questions. Centre text to the line and make words directly above it

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Comment: Yes Lucas any help would be greatly appreciated, I figured it would be simpler to post it all in the same question . And Temani I don’t want it centered to the page I want it centered to the horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

```
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Add text-align: center to logo class with your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that in your code, this entire chunk of CSS:

```css
.hr{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 35%;
}
```

is not having any effect, because there are no element with `class="hr"` in your HTML. You probably meant to target `<hr>` elements instead. You want `hr { ... }` instead of `.hr { ... }`. But since you seem content with your logo even though the rule doesn't apply, I opted to remove it.

To answer your first question, add `text-align: center` to `.logo`. Applying [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) to a container causes its text to be aligned accordingly. Using `center` for `text-align` causes the text to be centered relative to the container; other options include `left` (default), `right`, and `justify`.

For your second question, the spacing around the line is caused by CSS margins. Familiarize yourself with the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model), which describes how elements are represented on the page. An element can have a [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), a transparent area of space that surrounds it and pushes other elements out. [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) occurs to elements next to each other. Because of the user agent stylesheet applied by the browser before your CSS code, your `h1`, `hr`, and `h3` elements have margins by default. To remove the margins and put the words directly above and below the line, set `margin: 0` on them.

Final code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    .logo{
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1,hr,h3{
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>GTD</h1>
      <hr>
      <h3>Web Design</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```